# How to select top multiple of 10 entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

How to select top multiple of 10 entries?

I have a data in SQL table that is meaningful if only seen as bunch of 10 entries. I want to write a query that does this for ex. Select top 10*n from table where condition.

If for ex. 53 entries satisfy condition, I want only 50 to be seen and last 3 to be discarded.

Plz help.
Kbv

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please show evidence of what research you have done and both how this has been helpful and how it has not.  Please show a sample table with sample data as text in the Question (not as a linked file).  Please show what code you have tried formatted as a code sample (highlight code and click on the `{}` button above the text entry area).  Please show any error messages you are having difficulty with.  Please show as text in the question your desired output.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
declare @rows int;
set @rows = ((select count(*) from table where condition)/10)*10

select top @rows * from table where condition
```

Comment: Hello Psidom, SQL shows error in last line neat @rows. It says that integer, or real expected. Anything can be done for that?

Comment: OK mate, solved it. Just put a bracket around @rows in last line And works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with CTE AS (
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Condition
)
Select top(((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE)/10)*10) * From CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following...

```
SELECT orderField,
       field1,
       ...
FROM tblTable
WHERE condition
ORDER BY orderField
LIMIT 10 * numberOfGroups;
```

When constructing your query first decide which fields you want.  In a simple one table query you can use `SELECT *` fairly safely, but if you are referring to a `JOIN`ed dataset then you should consider specifying which fields you are going to use and assigning aliases to those fields.

Make sure that whatever your `orderField` or `orderFields` are called they are covered by a wildcard such as `*` or by being explicitly specified.

The above code first selects all records that meet your `criteria`.  It then sorts the resulting list based upon which field or fields you specify for `ORDER BY`.  Note : The above assumes that you are sorting based upon existing values in your table.  If you need to sort based on computed values then another (minor) level of complexity may need to be added.

`LIMIT` will then grab the first specified number of records from the sorted list.  `LIMIT` accepts simply computed values such as `2 * 2` or `10 * numberOfGroups`, where `numberOfGroups` is a variable set previously in the code or a value that explicitly replace `numberOfGroups` (i.e. `10 * @numberOfGroups` where `@numberOfGroups` has previously been set to `5` or `10 * 5`).

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.